# How do I Bind the function instead of creating a new one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. here I have a functional component. In which I have

```
const bginfo = useLocalStore(() => ({
      status: bgStatus,
      setStatus(val) {
        bginfo.status = val;
      }
    }));
return (
  <div className={css.root}>
    <Select
      onChange={(event) => bginfo.setStatus(event.target.value)}
      value={bginfo.status}
      id="bgStatus"
    />
```

SO, In this , Now instead of creating new instance I want to `bind function here instead of creating new instance.`

How do I do this ? Can any one help me with this ?.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function and pass to onChange, it automatically have the `event` passed if you use it with `onChange`/`onClick`

```
setStatus = (event) => {
  bginfo.setStatus(event.target.value);
}

<Select
  onChange={setStatus}
  value={bginfo.status}
  id="bgStatus"
/>
```

Here's an official example from the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

Comment: @ganeshThis could cause some unwanted side effects.  It's a good practice to still pass the event and all the call the function.

Also use `event.preventdefault()` as the first line in the funtion to prevent unwanted re-render when you do this with `onClick`.

Comment: @AdamHinckley So for I have no problem with that, would you mind leaving an example or a link about the "unwanted side effects"? :)

Comment: have you tried that on a button?  `preventdefault()` prevents the browser from reloading the page when it's clicked.  Also if you don't do an anonomous funtion for onClick there are situations where the browser will crash from too many re-renders.

Comment: @AdamHinckley I mean I don't think obtaining the event automatically will cause any unwanted side effect as that is stated officially in the React Docs I don't think there's any problem with that. Check my update. For `preventdefault()`, you're right, but it's the op's choice whether to use it. There're example in the docs without it too.